# Two step user approval after registration

Tags: users

I'm new to Drupal, and need help on user registration.

- A user registers on the site by filling in fields which include: name , DOB, users email(user1), password and official contact email address(ocea).
- Once the form is submitted, an email goes to official contact email address(ocea). The user is approved once the administrator will give his consent.

How I can I achieve this? A module? Rules?

Comment: Do you want two separate website administrators to approve the new user? Or you want the new user to register, receive a verification email, and then the final approval is left up to the site administrator? (Like kiamlaluno's answer below?)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any third-party modules. Drupal core has the option to verify the email the user enters, and the option for the administrator user to approve the accounts users create. In Drupal 7, those settings are on `/admin/config/people/accounts`.

> [image: screenshot]

As for name, and date of birth, those are fields you can add to user accounts. In Drupal 7, those settings are on `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`.

> [image: screenshot]